# False negative probability

Tags: probability, biology

Probability applied to bio:

Two clinical tests can be performed to diagnose an illness. The First test A has a reliability of 999/1000, test B has a reliability of 99/100. Test B is only performed after test A.
What is the probability to have a false negative after those two tests?
The probability of having the illness is unknown.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please show your attempts!

Comment: Not sure it is 0.001*0.01... can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does reliability mean? Since you do not know the probability of having the illness, the best you can do might be to find the probability of an overall false negative given you actually have the illness.   Are the tests independent? Does one negative  result and one positive result count as positive?

Comment: One negative result and one positive result count as positive, correct

Comment: Reliability means, e.g. for test A, that in 1/1000 of cases, we have an incorrect result. You're ill but test is negative, or you not ill but result is positive.